# how to remove the 3rd dimension for gray image in opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, alliedvision

I use *Allied Vision* camera to capture frame, and their *Vimba* API, but stuck in 3 channel grayscale image.

```
with Vimba.get_instance() as vimba:
            cams = vimba.get_all_cameras()
            with cams[0] as camera:
                recv_image = camera.get_frame()
                recv_image.convert_pixel_format(PixelFormat.Mono8)
                t1 = recv_image.as_opencv_image()
                #t1 has a dimension (xx,xx,1), I want to remove the last channel
                cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(t1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                #not working as cv2.cvtcolor does not take (xx,xx,1) input
```

**update:**even Christoph shows a numpy way to convert 3-d to 2-d, but I found I could not use some OpenCV commands, how to convert it back to OpenCV image? anyway I temporarily use a very stupid way to serve the purpose, but I still want the neat way to do this

```
 recv_image.convert_pixel_format(PixelFormat.Mono8)
 cv2.imwrite('cv2image.jpg', recv_image.as_opencv_image())
 cv2image = cv2.imread('cv2image.jpg',0)
```

Update: finally I could use numpy to do this instead of saving image, thanks to christoph

```
frame.convert_pixel_format(PixelFormat.Mono8)
                        a = frame.as_opencv_image()
                        b = np.array(a)
                        cv2image = np.squeeze(b)
```

Comment: Check the shape of `cv2image`

Comment: thanks, actually I noticed cv2image is not updated as cv2.cvtcolor does not accept the t1, which has a dimension (xx,xx,1), but anyway I still need to get rid of 1 in (xx,xx,1), I just updated

Comment: simply reshape, or call `.squeeze()` which removes dimensions of size 1. it's numpy.

Comment: what is `recv_image`? what other libraries are involved here? need a complete "picture"/[mre]. "opencv" pictures, in python, are nothing but numpy arrays. a `as_opencv_image` method is silly. it should have been named "as numpy array" (or simply support the buffer protocol, so `np.array(recv_image)` would work

Comment: with Vimba.get_instance() as vimba:
                cams = vimba.get_all_cameras()
                with cams[0] as camera: recv_image = camera.get_frame()   I just updated the post

Comment: then just say `recv_image.as_opencv_image().squeeze()`

Comment: what was the error message you get from opencv?

Comment: `b = np.array(a)` is pointless. it's a numpy array already.. that's my expectation of `as_opencv_image` anyway